# Coping Array(or variable) without the copy just being a reference to the original variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, copy, clone

I'm making a chess game in javascript and I wan't to make a copy of the board array so I can modify the board and easily restore it to it's a original state. I don't want to use J Query and have already tried to use slice(0) to copy the variable but that din't seem to work. Does anyone know how to copy an array(or variable for that matter)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If the board is a 2-d array, say a row array containing column arrays, you would need to create a new row array and slice the original column array entries.

Answer (score 1):

```
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
let strArray = JSON.stringify(array)
let backup = JSON.parse(strArray)
```

Comment: this solution has seemed to work thank you for helping